# VB.NET and Crystal Reports - datasets and more

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, dataset

I'm not sure if this is even possible but here goes:

Currently I have a crystal report with a few header fields and detail lines ( of course)
I pass a dataset containing a header datatable and a detail datatable. Everything works as expected... as long as I have only 1 record in the header table. What I would like to be able to do is somehow make the report "repeat" if there are multiple records in the header datatable. Is this possible? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the report header will only appear once. You could insert a group, and bind the group to the data in the header datatable, then remove the default header and footer rows that are added when you add a table to a report. This might mean adding the data in your detail table as a sub-report, and putting the sub-report in detail area.